# How to select all label elements on UITableViewCell for updating datetime at interval?

Tags: ios, uitableview, datetime

I created a TableView with TableViewCell containing a label to display datetime info for every cell.

```
----------
Foo
2014-5-12
----------
Bar
2014-5-13
----------
Hello world
2014-5-14
----------
```

I want to update all datetime at intervals of time, so I need to select all labels that are displaying datetime, and then update their text content using iteration.

I know using `tableView.reloadData` to refresh all cell elements can do this stuff, but I think this is not the effective solution.

Comment: Why do you think its not effective to do `[tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: @bhargavg It will redraw all cell elements again. All I want is just update a part of the cell, not the whole.

Comment: you want to update all cell's date label? or only a particular cell?

Comment: All cell's date label.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to update time `UILabel`s inside all `UITableViewCell`s, I would suggest you do the following:

- Update the model backing your `UITableView`
- Call `[tableView reloadData]`

Don't worry about this method being inefficient, it is not.

Also, Don't try to update the `UITableViewCell`s content directly without updating the model first. Because of cell reuse, your changes will be gone if the `UITableView` is scrolled

Comment: +1 for remembering to mention updating the model. Though since they are just displaying time/date based information... I don't think that will be an issue when creating a new cell. Oh well, keep the +1 =)

Comment: I have some text field element inside the cell. The text field will be blurred if `reloadData` is refreshing while I'm inputing something. So what I want is get all date labels and update them independently.

Answer (score 0):

You could...

1. Create a subclass of UILabel that observers a notification that you post when enough time has passed.
2. Add a method to each of your cells to tell them to update their labels, and when whatever time interval has passed, update the onscreen cells with tableView.visibleCells
3. If the time interval that is passing is regular, you could add an NSTimer when you dequeue the cells and have them all update themselves (probably the worst solution, but it could work depending on your case)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this?

```
for(YourTableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   YourModel *model = ...; // get your model at indexPath
   ... // get and update the date of model
   NSString *dateString = ... // generate string for display
   cell.dateLabel.text = dateString;
}
```